# Instead of hosting site Manually, Create a Installer file for hosting website/web Application in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Created a website and our client don't want to use net to access that site(I know its strange but its true)
so i have only one option left, Host site on client system locally but is there any way to create a installer file for it. Instead of hosting site Manually, Create a Installer file for hosting website/web Application in asp.net.

Comment: I dont think so and it's something if existing I'd not recommend. Provided that you host it in a windows server IIS I'd suggest you configure accounts for running the service and configuring the service and the security and other tweaks in the IIS. All thou, a company I know is creating an web application to enable ease of web application productions directly to the IIS servers. You can connect it to TFS and do buildscripts so you release to different environments by running a buildscript in the IIS or you point to a location of where the files are. I'd suggest you look for such a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, You can do that. Please see this link

[Step by Step Guide to Create a Setup for a Web Application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shrijeetnair/StepbyStepSetup11102005033122AM/StepbyStepSetup.aspx)

In the  final step an **msi**  file has generated at applications bin/debug folder.You can supply this **msi** the target machine(to your client), when you run this **msi** at target machine, it will create a virtual directory as well as create same folder structure, which you have specified in File System. This installer will also install the specified those libraries in the registry which are specified in the Registry.

Now you can browse that application at the target machine in same way as you have done at your own machine.

**If you are using VisualStudio 2012 or 2013** .Please follow this link.[creating-setup-for-web-application-using-install-shield](http://cipherdyn.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/creating-setup-for-web-application-using-install-shield-le/)

Comment: but when i am adding a new project and Click on Setup and deployment there is only one option 'Enable InstallShield Limited Edition'

Comment: @VishalPandey Your visualstudio version ?

Comment: Its .net frame work 4.5 So You are using Visual studio 2012 or 2013 , The setup project in **Visual studio 2012 or 2013** can be created using visual studio template InstallShield .Please see [how to create setup project in VS 12 or 13](http://www.brainbrushups.com/2014/02/how-to-create-setup-project-in-visual.html)

Comment: @VishalPandey Please see this link . It will guide you to create setup for web application .[creating-setup-for-web-application-using-install-shield](http://cipherdyn.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/creating-setup-for-web-application-using-install-shield-le/)